# Filter list of object with condition in Python

Tags: python

**I have a list structure like this:**

```
listpost =
[
   {
      "post_id":"01",
      "text":"abc",
      "time": datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 15, 53, 19),
      "type":"normal",
   },
   {
      "post_id":"02",
      "text":"nothing",
      "time":datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 15, 53, 19),
      "type":"normal",
   }
]
```

I want to filter the list by text in [text] key if only the [text] has "abc"

so the example will look like this

```
listpost =
[
   {
      "post_id":"01",
      "text":"abc",
      "time": datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 15, 53, 19),
      "type":"normal",
   }
]
```

My code:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

listposts = []

for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=1):
    listposts.append(post)
print(listposts)
```

Comment: What is your question? Why did you not use an `if` statement to only append `post` if `post['text']` is equal to `'abc'`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you specifically asked about filtering the list you have, you can use `filter` builtin with `lambda` to filter out the elements from the list.

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x.get('text', '')=='abc', listpost))

[{'post_id': '01', 'text': 'abc', 'time': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 5, 15, 53, 19), 'type': 'normal'}]
```

But I'd recommend to filter it out upfront before actually appending it to the list, to avoid unnecessary computations due to the need to re-iterate the items i.e. appending only the items that match the criteria.

Something like this:

```py
for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=1):
    if <post match the condition>:
        listposts.append(post)  # append the post
```

Answer (score 8):

simple like that:

```
filtered_list = [e for e in listpost if e['text'] == 'abc']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter elements that are exactly "abc"

```
new_list = [el for el in listpost if el["text"]=="abc"]
```

If you want to keep elements that starts with "abc"

```
new_list = [el for el in listpost if el["text"].startswith("abc")]
```

If you want to keep elements that contains the "abc" substring

```
new_list = [el for el in listpost if "abc" in el["text"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 list(filter(lambda x: x['text']=='abc', listpost))
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

A good pythonic solution is already given, but here's another solution closer to what you were trying:

```py
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

listposts = []
wanted = "abc"  # wanted post
for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=1):
    if t:=post.get("text", "") == wanted:
        # print("Found", t)
        listposts.append(post) 
    else:
        pass
        # print("Not found")
print(listposts)
```

Comment: What if i want to change the `==` to `in` ?. Cause i want to check if `abc` is contain inside the `text` key or not and not equal.

Comment: When i put contain like this`if wanted in post.get("text", ""):`  it will keep showing two same element instead of one

Comment: @johnny2000 the ```if wanted in post.get("text", ""):``` should work fine. In case of duplicates, you can always make the list a set and then back to list. I.e. ```s = set(current_list); new_list=list(s)```. This should only keep the unique elements.

Comment: Just now i tried it worked ! But after a couple times it should me `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`